# How to return a Mongoose object from saveAsync?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I've promisified Mongoose with Bluebird - all seems to work fine except that documents returned by `saveAsync()` are just plain objects and lack methods/virtuals.

```
order.saveAsync().then(function(order) {
  order.save(); // errors with object has no method 'save'
```

I am using 'save' as an example but no builtin method or my custom methods seem to be available.

How can I get a Mongoose object returned from `saveAsync`?

Comment: Does this work? `var orderObj= new Order(order); orderObj.save();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The save callback is called with multiple arguments - the object and the `numberAffected`. Therefore the promise is fulfilled with an array `[object, numberAffected]`. (this changes in 3.0)

So you can dereference the array (manually or get), spread or:

```
 order.saveAsync().then(function(result) {
     var order = result[0];
     return order._id;
 });
```

Using get

```
 order.saveAsync().get(0).then(function(order) {
      return order._id;
 });
```

Using spread

```
 order.saveAsync().spread(function(order, numberAffected) {
      return order._id;
 });
```